# How to detect corners in opencv just like matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I wrote a code in MATLAB and now want to convert it to openCV. The problem that I am facing is that in MATLAB corner detection is done by a simple command of `corner()` and it gives me the output in the form of an array of (x,y) coordinates of detected corners.
Now openCV documentation gives me [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html).
There are two issues in using `cornerHarris()` function.

1. It does not give me the (x,y) coordinates of corners.
2. I have to choose different threshold value for each image, whereas `corner()` in MATLAB used to do this by itself.

Any function that does these 2 things will be much appreciated as I am new to openCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the most similar function in OpenCV is:

```
goodFeaturesToTrack
```

Here is the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//----------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN
//----------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // src image
    Mat src;
    // dst image
    Mat dst;
    // Image loading
    namedWindow("result");
    namedWindow("src");
    src=imread("d:\\ImagesForTest\\lena.jpg",0);    

    cv::cvtColor(src,dst,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    Mat corners;
    cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(src,corners,50,0.01,20.0);

    for(int i=0;i<corners.rows;++i)
    {
        circle(dst,cv::Point(corners.at<float>(i,0),corners.at<float>(i,1)),3,Scalar(255,0,0),-1,CV_AA);
    }

    imshow("src",src);
    imshow("result",dst);
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    // Wait key press
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: i have seen that you are using `#pragma once`. I am having problem with using `pragma` stuff and i have mentioned my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710791/how-to-set-openmp-for-multithreading-in-ubuntu-12-04-for-an-opencv-project?noredirect=1#comment32828461_21710791

Comment: You can comment/remove it safely.

Comment: no no...i am not asking about your this post...i have an another project in which i want to use "pragma" but i am facing some problems...so can you help me in that...i have posted my question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710791/how-to-set-openmp-for-multithreading-in-ubuntu-12-04-for-an-opencv-project/21712492?noredirect=1#21712492

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `goodFeaturesToTrack()` method will give you the corner points which have `x (i.e. column index)` and `y(i.e. row index)`

see the code below:

```
void goodFeatureToTrack(Mat Vx) 
{ 

    /// Parameters for Shi-Tomasi algorithm
    vector<Point2f> cornersVx;
    int maxCorners = 100;
    double qualityLevel = 0.01;
    double minDistance = 10;
    int blockSize = 3;
    bool useHarrisDetector = false;
    double k = 0.04;

    goodFeaturesToTrack( Vx, cornersVx, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance, Mat(), blockSize, useHarrisDetector, k );



    for(int i=0; i<cornersVx.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n Point for VX:  "<<cornersVx[i].x<<"  "<<cornersVx[i].y;
    }


}
```