# How to set openMP for Multithreading in ubuntu 12.04 for an openCV project?

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, gcc

I want to do multi threading in one of my `for loop` using `#pragma omp parallel`. So, i am writing the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i=0; i<square->total; i++)
{
......
}
```

My project have a CMakeList.txt and Makefile. ***I don't understand, how do i tell the compiler and linker to use openMP?***

**Updates:**

I have edited my `CMakeList.txt` with following code

```
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

and then i did `cmake ..` and got the following result at terminal:

-- The C compiler identification is GNU

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]

-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED

-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success

-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]

-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED

-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success

-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

Comment: You're missing one `for`.

Comment: which "for" and where?

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for for(int i=0; i<square->total; i++)`

Comment: yes, i tried...but same error that "i has not been declared in this scope"...but if i remove this "pragma" stuff then the program runs

Comment: OP, if my attempt at an answer below doesn't help, please give us a complete but simple example (with main() and #includes and a (simple) loop body), including how you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@user2440724**

I wrote the code sample as you ask:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//----------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN
//----------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#ifdef _OPENMP 
#pragma omp parallel for
#endif
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      std::cout << "A" << std::endl;    
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

in vs2010 you need enable openmp as shown below:
[image]

Good tutorial for linux here: http://goulassoup.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/openmp-tutorial/
And GNU OpenMP docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/index.html#toc_Top

Comment: Hi, as i mentioned, i am using ubuntu. I have updated my problem, kindly have a look on it.

Comment: I've added the link to tutorial for linux (as mentioned there it was tested for ubuntu).

Comment: thanks but i still didn't understand how to run my program with openMP...i have included the things required in my `CMakeList.txt` and i am able to build my project with `make`..no error...but don't know how to tell them that i want to use openMP

Comment: thanks..i have read both the links but i am stuck at how to set the flag `-fopenmp`

Comment: Are you sure that it doesnt use OpenMP? You can check maximum number of threads supported by your system try check it: int MAX_THREADS = omp_get_max_threads(); Also you can get number of processors: int N_PROC = omp_get_num_procs();

Comment: thanks..i did the test and i received MAX_THREADS=4 and N_PROC=4...it means it is working but still no improvement in my project.

Comment: Using multithreading not always gives you speed up (for speed improvement you should organize your program in right way), sometimes it need significant time for controlling threads and this lead to longer running time than with single thread.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions...i am so much stuck with the computational time thing but now atleast  i know something about multithreading

Answer (score 2):

The `#pragma ...` should be on its own line.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<square->total; i++)
{
......
}
```

Make sure you don't forget the `for` at the end of the `#pragma`.

First make sure it works with the `#pragma` line commented out, then adding the line should be fine (assuming everything inside the loop is OK to parallelize, no concurrency issues or whatnot).

Also make sure you pass `-fopenmp` to both the compiler and the linker, and you have `#include <omp.h>` at the top.

Comment: thanks...how to pass `-fopenmp` to comlier and the linker? My project is having CMakeList.txt and Makefile...after adding the lines you have mentioned, i just did `make` and ran my program...it didn't give any error but there was no improvement in comutational time

Comment: i have updated my question with some more steps i have taken to use openMP.